# One-hot encoding using tf.data mixes up columns

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, one-hot-encoding

#### Minimum working examples

Consider the following CSV file (`example.csv`)

```
animal,size,weight,category
lion,large,200,mammal
ostrich,large,150,bird
sparrow,small,0.1,bird
whale,large,3000,mammal
bat,small,0.2,mammal
snake,small,1,reptile
condor,medium,12,bird
```

The goal is to convert all the categorical values into one-hot encodings. The [standard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) way to do this in Tensorflow 2.0 is to use `tf.data`. Following that example, the code to deal with the dataset above is

```
import collections
import tensorflow as tf

# Load the dataset.
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    'example.csv',
    batch_size=5,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)

# Specify the vocabulary for each category.
categories = collections.OrderedDict()
categories['animal'] = ['lion', 'ostrich', 'sparrow', 'whale', 'bat', 'snake', 'condor']
categories['size'] = ['large', 'medium', 'small']
categories['category'] = ['mammal', 'reptile', 'bird']

# Define the categorical feature columns.
categorical_columns = []
for feature, vocab in categories.items():
  cat_col = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
        key=feature, vocabulary_list=vocab)
  categorical_columns.append(tf.feature_column.indicator_column(cat_col))

# Retrieve the first batch and apply the one-hot encoding to it.
iterator = iter(dataset)
first_batch = next(iterator)
categorical_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(categorical_columns)

print(categorical_layer(first_batch).numpy())
```

#### Question

Running the code above, one gets

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

where it looks like the two last columns `size` and `category` have been flipped, despite the fact that `categories` is an *ordered* dictionary and the pre-existing order of the columns in the actual dataset. It's as if `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list()` did some unwarranted alphabetical sorting of the columns.

What's the reason for the above. Is this really the best way to do one-hot encoding in the spirit of `tf.data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Where is the sorting?

The sorting isn't occuring at `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list()`. If you print `categorical_columns`, you will see that the columns are still in the order you added them to the feature_column:

```
[
  IndicatorColumn(categorical_column=VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='animal', vocabulary_list=('lion', 'ostrich', 'sparrow', 'whale', 'bat', 'snake', 'condor'), dtype=tf.string, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0)),
  IndicatorColumn(categorical_column=VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='size', vocabulary_list=('large', 'medium', 'small'), dtype=tf.string, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0)),
  IndicatorColumn(categorical_column=VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='category', vocabulary_list=('mammal', 'reptile', 'bird'), dtype=tf.string, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0))
]
```

The sorting occurs in the [tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/DenseFeatures) object.

In the code, you can see where the sorting occurs [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cf7fcf164c9846502b21cebb7d3d5ccf6cb626e8/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py#L2758) (I found this by tracing the class inheritance from the [tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cf7fcf164c9846502b21cebb7d3d5ccf6cb626e8/tensorflow/python/feature_column/dense_features_v2.py#L28) class to the [tensorflow.python.feature_column.dense_features.DenseFeatures](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cf7fcf164c9846502b21cebb7d3d5ccf6cb626e8/tensorflow/python/feature_column/dense_features.py#L30) class to the [tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column_v2._BaseFeaturesLayer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cf7fcf164c9846502b21cebb7d3d5ccf6cb626e8/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py#L360) class to the [_normalize_feature_columns](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cf7fcf164c9846502b21cebb7d3d5ccf6cb626e8/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py#L2716) function).

## Why is it sorted?

So why is it sorted? [Elsewhere](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cf7fcf164c9846502b21cebb7d3d5ccf6cb626e8/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py#L1047) in the same file containing the `_normalize_feature_columns` function (which is the function where the data is sorted), there is a similar sorting function with this comment:

```
# Sort the columns so the default collection name is deterministic even if the
# user passes columns from an unsorted collection, such as dict.values().
```

I think this explanation applies to why columns are sorted when using the `tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures` class too. Your columns and data are are consistent, but tensorflow doesn't assume that the input will be consistent, so it sorts it to ensure a consistent order.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough investigation. I think that TensorFlow's rationale for sorting under the hood will be a source of confusion for many, though...